# Multiple html, head, body found with PHP xPath

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath

I'm using CURL, DOMDocument, loadHTML, DOMXPath in PHP to get the contents of URLs. In order to verify the validity of the data, I also run checks on the amount of html, head and body tags that were retrieved.

My setup is working fine for the large majority of URLs I enter. However, for some URLs, an unexpected amount of those tags in reported. The xPaths:

```
$html = $this->runXpath('/html');
$head = $this->runXpath('/html/head');
$body = $this->runXpath('/html/body');
```

And the check:

```
if($html->length > 1) {
 echo 'Too many html tags';
}
```

- https://www.chownow.com/: 2x HTML (yes, I see the iframe, but that is generated through Javascript, which CURL shouldn't render? Also, the xpath states that the html should be a child of #document - which, according to $tag->parentNode->nodeName both HTML elements are? The second HTML tag also doesn't show up in neither 'View source' nor the responsebody from the CURL request).
- http://neilpatel.com/: 2x HTML? (Once again a video, but seemingly not even a relevant iframe tag in the DOM source).
- https://www.groovehq.com/: 2x BODY? (An iframe again, but no double html error, but a double body error instead?).

**Questions**

1. Why does xpath seem to think there are multiple instances of those tags, while I can't find them as such in the CURL response body using ctrl-f when I output it, nor in 'View source'?
2. How can I "see what xpath sees" in order to debug similar cases?
3. It would almost seem that DOMDocument or xpath parses javascript, does it? If not, how do I explain the examples above?

Any additional questions I will gladly answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the last example url ( https://www.groovehq.com/ ) has 3 `<body>` tags visible in the HTML source code. I haven't checked the others. Each of the urls listed however fail to validate at validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks for your reply! These <body> tags are placed within a <script> tag and I therefore don't see how the xpath I'm using would return/consider those?